# Reachability or connectionDidFailWithError?

Tags: iphone, networking, nsurlconnection, reachability

I have implemented connectionDidFailWithError to alert the user of any errors that happen in the network connections like time out, no internet connection etc. 
It gives me correct notification when no internet connection is available.

So do I still need to implement Apple's reachability code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you handle every possible scenario of no connectivity on all your connection attempts and report to the user that you cannot connect, you should be ok.

it is easier to just have a main connectivity checking mechanism and test connectivity prior to making your request.

for instance, i had a mapview that i checked my connection to my service but not the internet for the mapview to grab tile images and it got rejected because if the mapview didnt have a connection, nothing would show up in the map and it didnt tell the user...